# Use SQL to exclude rows with no change in specific column from query

Tags: sql, filtering

How can I exclude the yellow highlighted rows? The requirement of the query is to return only rows where the job title changed, but the raw data includes extraneous rows with different effective dates which we want to be able to automatically exclude with SQL.

This is because the source system has a record effective date column that is common to several columns. We cannot change this architecture and so need the ability to exclude records from the output.

[image]

Edit to include error image from suggested answer:

[image]

Comment: why the vote to close this.  This is a good question in light of OP's inability to change the table structure and need for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select
a.*
FROM 
jobtitles a
LEFT JOIN jobtitles b
ON a.id = b.id AND
a.effdate < b.effdate
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

something like that, that would get the latest job title anyway

you might be able to use that "pseudo table" to further query

on considering your question further, how about

```sql
select
MIN(effdate) as effdate, jobtitle
FROM jobtitles
group by employeeid, jobtitle
```

(I'm making the assumption they don't change job titles back and forth, if so you're basically screwed, so be aware of that)

Answer (score 0):

If `JobTitle` of an employee does not reverted to previous job titles, use the following query:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, 
    Name, 
    JobTitle, 
    MAX(Name) AS Name, 
    MIN(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
FROM jobtitles
GROUP BY EmployeeID, JobTitle
ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC, EffectiveDate DESC
```

If `JobTitle` of employees can be reverted/change to title that they have already obtained in the past, use the following query:

Edit: Update query according to table schema provided in question

```
SELECT ASSOCIATE_ID, 
    JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION,
    POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ASSOCIATE_ID, 
    JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION,
    JOB_TITLE_CODE,
    POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
    LEAD(JOB_TITLE_CODE,1, '0') OVER (ORDER BY ASSOCIATE_ID ASC, POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC) AS PREV_TITLE_ID
  FROM EMP_JOB_HISTORY
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.PREV_TITLE_ID <> tmp.JOB_TITLE_CODE
```

Comment: Thanks Nguyen!  I put the second option in and it seems to be looking for the job titles to be numeric values.  Is there a way to adapt this to work around the job titles being strings?

Comment: Hi Gavin. I created a sample table with `JobTitle` as varchar(255) and it works fine. Can you provide more details on the error you are having?

Comment: Hi Nguyen - I just edited the post to paste a screenshot of the error in snowflake.

Comment: Hi Gavin. By looking at the error, I would guess that the error occurs when comparing `JobTitle` (varchar) with 0 (generated when using `Lead`). Try changing it to `Lead(JobTitle,1,'0') OVER (Order By EmployeeID ASC, EffectiveDate DESC) AS PrevTitle` and see if it fixes anything. Also, I looked at your table schema and would suggest that you use `JOB_TITLE_CODE` instead of `JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION` as it would be prone to fewer errors. I also updated my answer to accommodate with your table schema. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Hi Nguyen, this solution did work, partially!  The flaw I found (likely due to my explanation of the problem) was that seemed to only exclude the first instance of a duplicate record.  I took the LEAD / OVER portion and adapted it to add a flag where the title didn't match the previous record (using as 'title_change_flag'.  The flag worked except when I tried to add a 'where title_change_flag = 'Y' clause at the end, I get a syntax error about the window function.  I'm editing the post to show you the updated code and error.